# Picture from MediaLibrary to Base64 String

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, base64

I have the following code to retrieve a picture from camera roll:

```
private string getBase64Image(Geophoto item)
{
    MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
    var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
    foreach (var picture in pictures)
    {
        var camerarollPath = picture.GetPath();
        if (camerarollPath == item.ImagePath)
        {
            // Todo Base64 convert here
        }
    }

    return "base64";
}
```

My question is now how to convert a `Picture` to a `Base64` string?

Comment: I can imagine you want to convert ImagePath (not sure what datatype it is) to string, and then 

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToConvert);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Comment: item.ImagePath only contains the path to the image. I need to convert the image itself not the path to the image ...

Comment: get the image object, convert image to bytes. Convert bytes to Base64 string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `Stream` from the `Picture` instance using the `GetStream` method. Get the byte array from the stream. Convert bytes into the Base64 string using the  `Convert.ToBase64String` method.

```
Stream imageStream = picture.GetImage();
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
    // this is the Base64 string you are looking for
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i only had to change picture.GetStream() to picture.GetImage()

Comment: Thanks for this comment. You are right - I've updated the answer.